# Show details by category

Tags: php

I am just trying to get a clue on how to do this:

I'm almost done with my php classified ads. Everything works perfect, and thanks for your help.

My database: category, subcategory, state, city, classified

The classified table contains the following:

id, title, description, price, make, mileage, surface, bedrooms, name, number, state, city.

Now if someone clicks on an ad, it redirects to details.php that show the ad detail.

What I want to do is if someone selects an ad that's related to cars, the details.php will show only the details related to car, without even echoing surface and bedrooms that related to real estate category. Like this:

Title
name:
number:
state:
city:
price: 
mileage: 
make: 
description:
 And viceversa, if a real estate ad is selected, I only want title, description, price, surface, bedrooms... Like this:

Title
name:
number:
state:
city:
price: 
surface:
bedrooms: 
description:

So far if I specify car and house options in the description, but I want each category to be unique. Here is the code that echos the ad details :

```
     <td>
       <div><a href='details-" . $id . ".php'><img src='" . $picture . "'          

     width='110' height='90' /></a></div>
      </td>

     <td><a href='details-" . $id . ".php'>" . $title . "</a><br />


      <a href='details-" . $id . ".php'>" . $description . "</a>" . 
      </td>



      <td>
      <div>$" . $price . "  </div>
  </td>
```

I don't even know how to form a question, sorry for that.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add php tags `<?php ?>` when displaying php variables try this

```
  <td>
       <div><a href='details-" <?php echo $id ?> ".php'><img src='" <?php echo $picture ?>"'          
     width='110' height='90' /></a></div>
      </td>
     <td><a href='details-" <?php echo $id ?> ".php'>" <?php echo $title ?> "</a><br />
      <a href='details-" <?php echo $id ?> ".php'>" <?php echo $discription ?>"</a>" . 
      </td>
      <td>
      <div>$" <?php  echo $price ?> "  </div>
  </td>
```

Comment: Well, thanks, but I already got that working. I am not sure if you understood the question.